# HP Proliant DL360p gen8 Unrecoverable Media Error. Amber lights on 3 disks

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, raid5

I have HP Proliant DL360p gen8. 4 disk on RAID 5, 3 of them have amber light on them. I did chkdsk on my virtual machines none reported any error. 
Am i able to fix it without buying and replacing disks? If no then do i need to replace all 3 disks?

POST Message:

**SLOT 0 HP Smart Array p420i Controller (1GB v5.42) 1 Logical Drive 1716-Slot 0 Drive Array - Unrecoverable Media Errors Detected on Drives during previous Rebuild or background Surface Analysis (ARM) scan. Errors will be fixed automatically when the sector(s) are overwritten. Backup and Restore recommended.
1720-Slot 0 Drive Array - S.M.A.R.T. Hard Drive(s) Detect Imminent Failure:
port 1l: Box 1:Bays 1,2,3 
Do not replace drive unless all other drives in the array are on-line!**

Answer (score 0):

Following this hpe article

```
https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00104843en_us&docLocale=en_US
```

they say you need backup all the data,
destroy and recreate all the array, make  drive erase for the whole array and if all is okay then restore back the data from backup.

kind of dumb instruction but we have what we have

also another article here

```
https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/shared/gen9/error/Advanced/Content/242703.htm
```

says that error 1716 means that

**A media error is detected on a drive and cannot be corrected because of degraded fault tolerance or a media error at the same location on another drive in the same array. An unrecoverable read error is returned to the operating system when this block address is read.**